# How exactly does one prove that $\forall x \; (x \notin x)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I often run into some version of the statement

$$\forall x \; (x \notin x)$$

...but it is not entirely clear to me how exactly one derives it formally.

Is this statement part of the *definition* of $\in$, somehow?

Alternatively, can it be deduced from the ZFC axioms?

I am aware of the fact that the RHS of the definition below

$$Q := \{x\;:\; x \notin x\}$$

plays a central role in Russell's paradox, but from this I can conclude only that $Q$ (whatever it may be) cannot be a set; I don't know exactly how to use this result to prove the universally-quantified expression given at the beginning of this post.

---

EDIT:
Here's my clumsy/noob-like attempt to flesh out @MauroALLEGRANZA's first comment.

It follows from the ***Axiom of Pairing***, that for every set $x$, the set $\{x, x\} = \{x\}$ exists.

The ***Axiom of Regularity*** can be expressed formally, as follows:
$$
\forall \;\mathrm{sets}\; v \;(v \neq \varnothing \Rightarrow (\exists w \in v)\; v \, \cap \, w = \varnothing)
$$

This means, in particular, that for every set $x$, since $\{x\} \neq \varnothing$ (by the ***Axiom of Extensionality***), there must exist a set $w \in \{x\}$ such that $\{x\} \, \cap \, w = \varnothing$.  Since, by definition, $x$ is the only set $y$ such that $y \in \{x\}$, $x$ must be the set $w$ whose existence the ***Axiom of Regularity*** guarantees.  Therefore, we must have that $\forall x \; (\{x\} \, \cap x = \varnothing)$.

This assertion implies that $\forall x\,\forall z (z \in \{x\} \Rightarrow z \notin x)$.  In particular, $$\forall x (x \in \{x\})  \Rightarrow \forall x (x \notin x)$$.

---

Once I write this proof all out in tedious detail, I realize that the ***Axiom of Regularity***, at least as stated above, depends on the existence of the set $\varnothing$.

The one proof I know of the existence of $\varnothing$ uses the ***Axiom Schema of Separation*** as justification for the existence of the set $\{u\;:\; u \in X \;\wedge\; u \neq u\}=:\varnothing$, where $X$ is the set whose existence is guaranteed by the ***Axiom of Infinity***.

In order for this definition of $\varnothing$ to conform to the usual sematics of $\varnothing$, we must have that
$$\neg \, (\exists x \; (x \neq x))$$

...or, equivalently,

$$\forall x \; (x = x)$$

This is not a ZFC axiom, as far as I can tell, so I figure this must be either an axiom of logic or part of the definition of $=$ .  (Sheesh, the search for "rock bottom" sure feels like it's "turtles all the way down"...)

Comment: See [Axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity): The axiom of regularity together with the axiom of pairing implies that no set is an element of itself.

Comment: No, it is not part of the def of $\in$. See [Non-wellfounded Set Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nonwellfounded-set-theory) i.e. set theories (different from $\mathsf {ZF}$) with sets which contain themselves as members.

Comment: See also the post [What is x∉x supposed to mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3522468/what-is-x-notin-x-supposed-to-mean)